# Status change by clicking image button in yii2

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii2

I am working on yii2 gridview and I want to change the status by clicking image.[image: here I got some image and I want to use them for status change.]

Here is my gridview code:`

```
      ['header'=>'Deleted',
      'format' => 'image',
      'value'=>function($data) { return $data->deleteimageurl; },],

      ['header'=>'Reports Status',
      'format' => 'image',
      'value'=>function($data) { return $data->statusimageurl; },],`
```

And in model I have created these functions in model to view the images using the image path:

```
public function getdeleteImageurl()
{
  return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/'.$this->is_deleted.'.png';
}

public function getstatusImageurl()
{
  return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/'.$this->reports_status.'.png';
}
```

Now How can I change the status? How can I add an ID in image column ? I can use ajax if I add an ID there.Or if there is any other solutions please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use format `raw` and value like as:

```
'value'=>function($data) {
    return HTML:img($data->statusimageurl, ['data-id'=>$data->id]);
},
```

After you can use ajax with `data-id`